# Unity resolving concrete classes to generic interfaces when available

Tags: generics, unity-container

I can resolve generic interfaces to generic classes like the common generic repository pattern.

```
IRepository<objectA> resolves to Repository<objectA>
IRepository<objectB> resolves to Repository<objectB>
```

But then for `objectC` I need a concrete Repository, namely `ObjectCRepository` that extends `Repository<objectC>`. If I register this won't there be two different registrations for for `IRepository<objectC>` and everything fails?

Comment: It can be done. Need to see your code.

Comment: Sorry haven't got the code as I wanted to know whether this was something that can be done first. But I'm having other problems with unity in getting it to configure right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809204/cant-resolve-types-from-unity-config-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be two registrations, but they don't conflict. Unity is smart enough to prefer fully defined closed generics over open ones. For example this works fine:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="ILog_Interface" type="Common.ILog`1, Common2"/>
    <alias alias="Logger_Class" type="Common.Logger`1, Common2"/>
    <alias alias="DemoServiceLog_Interface" type="Common.ILog`1[[Services.Demo.DemoService, Services.Demo]], Common2"/>
    <alias alias="DemoServiceLog_Class" type="Common.ServiceLogger`1[[Services.Demo.DemoService, Services.Demo]], Common2"/>

        <container name="DemoService">
          <register type="ILog_Interface" mapTo="Logger_Class"/>
          <register type="DemoServiceLog_Interface" mapTo="DemoServiceLog_Class"/>
        </container>
</unity>
```

Comment: Nice to know, So I can register the Concrete UserRepository : Repository<User> to IRepository<User> as well as the generic Repository<> to IRepository<> and it should just work out.