# Can't resolve types from unity config file

Tags: configuration, web-config, unity-container, app-config

Trying to set up Unity via XML configurations I'm getting this exception

```
The type name or alias ServiceHost could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.
```

Trying to comment that out I get the same exception for the next and then the next after that so the problem must lie somewhere in my setup.

```
<unity>
    <typeAliases>

      <!-- Lifetime manager types -->
      <typeAlias alias="singleton"
           type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager,
             Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
      <typeAlias alias="external"
           type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager,
             Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
      <typeAlias alias="perThread"
           type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.PerThreadLifetimeManager,
             Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />

      <!-- User-defined type aliases -->
      <typeAlias alias="ServiceHost"
                 type="System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost, System.ServiceModel" />
      <typeAlias alias="UnityServiceHost"
                 type="MyProjectServiceLibrary.Hosting.UnityServiceHost" />

      <typeAlias alias="IServiceBehavior"
                 type="System.ServiceModel.Descriptions.IServiceBehavior, System.ServiceModel" />
      <typeAlias alias="UnityServiceBehavior"
                 type="MyProjectServiceLibrary.Hosting.UnityServiceBehavior, MyProjectServiceLibrary" />

      <typeAlias alias="IInstanceProvider"
                 type="System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IInstanceProvider, System.ServiceModel" />
      <typeAlias alias="UnityInstanceProvider"
                 type="MyProjectServiceLibrary.Hosting.UnityInstanceProvider, MyProjectServiceLibrary" />

      <typeAlias alias="MyProjectService"
                 type="MyProjectServiceLibrary.Service.MyProjectService, MyProjectServiceLibrary" />

      <typeAlias alias="IRepositoryFactory"
                 type="MyProjectDataModelLibrary.Repository.IRepositoryFactory, MyProjectDataModelLibrary" />
      <typeAlias alias="RepositoryFactory"
                 type="MyProjectDataModelLibrary.Repository.RepositoryFactory, MyProjectDataModelLibrary" />

      <typeAlias alias="IDbContext"
                 type="MyProjectDataModelLibrary.DataContext.IDbContext, MyProjectDataModelLibrary" />
      <typeAlias alias="MyProjectDatabase"
                 type="MyProjectDataModelLibrary.DataContext.MyProjectDatabase, MyProjectDataModelLibrary" />

      <typeAlias alias="IRepositoryOfT"
                 type="MyProjectDataModelLibrary.Repository.IRepository`1, MyProjectDataModelLibrary" />
      <typeAlias alias="EntityRepositoryOfT"
                 type="MyProjectDataModelLibrary.Repository.EntityRepository`1, MyProjectDataModelLibrary" />

    </typeAliases>

    <containers>

      <container>
        <types>

          <type type="MyProjectService" />

          <type type="ServiceHost"
                mapTo="UnityServiceHost" />

          <type type="IServiceBehavior"
                mapTo="UnityServiceBehavior" />

          <type type="IInstanceProvider"
                mapTo="UnityInstanceProvider" />

          <type type="IRepositoryFactory"
                mapTo="RepositoryFactory" />

          <type type="IDbContext"
                mapTo="MyProjectDatabase" />

          <type type="IRepositoryOfT"
                mapTo="EntityRepositoryOfT" />

        </types>
      </container>

    </containers>
  </unity>
```

I've tried reading around to see what I'm doing wrong. I doubt it's the fully qualified name though I can't be sure as I haven't really used that before.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterInstance<IUnityContainer>(container);
UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
section.Configure(container);
```

The exception is thrown in the last line here.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? Looks like 1.2, but just wanted to verify.

Comment: <typeAlias alias="UnityServiceHost" type="MyProjectServiceLibrary.Hosting.UnityServiceHost" /> type is missing an assembly name

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But that doesn't seem to be the problem because he's throwing the exception on every type.

Comment: Then you're going to have to figure it out the hard way: Remove all but one mapping, make that one work, add one more mapping, repeat. You have way too many mappings with "MyProject" for someone without the code to help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're referencing system types, it's most likely trying to pull those types from the GAC. In that case, you'll need to use the fully qualified assembly names, including version number, culture, and public key token. Something like this:

```
<typeAlias alias="ServiceHost"
  type="System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost, System.ServiceModel,
  Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, 
  processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

You'll need to look up the appropriate version # and public key tokens for the version of .NET you're using, of course.